# Display Drupal 6 menu in Zend web application

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework, menu, drupal-6

I have a Zend web application running next to Drupal 6. The basic structure is like this:

```
www.domain.com/cms/
www.domain.com/zf/
```

CMS is Drupal content, and ZF is Zend Framework content.

Here's the question. I'm looking to place the primary/secondary links from Drupal into the ZF menus so that the pages are relatively seamless as you navigate between the CMS and Zend. Currently there's an Ajax call being done in Zend to get the primary links from Drupal. This is inefficient and shows up on reports, thus why I'm tasked with fixing it.

Conceptually, what might be the best way to do this? Should I include a file from Drupal in my ZF app, or something else? I have very little knowledge of Drupal, so I'm not sure if I can just do a database call to get the links, or if there's a function I should be calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id' say the best way is to export the Drupal menu in some kind of format and then parse it in your ZF application. And to keep it in sync just write a small script that does the export and run it daily or whatever suits your needs (preferably when your site has the lowest traffic, if performance is a priority).

Here is a list of functions related to Drupal menu: [Menu system](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/6)

This is something that will get you started:

```
  $menus = menu_get_menus();
  foreach ($menus as $menu_machine_name => $menu_human_name) {
    $menu_items = menu_tree_all_data($menu_machine_name);
  }
```

But you'd have to bootstrap Drupal, to have access to all the Drupal's function. So you can do something like this:

```
require_once 'path/to/drupal/folder/installation/includes/bootstrap.inc'; 
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); // you now have access to all Drupal functions
```

And of course you could just do a direct database call, but first you have to see how Drupal gets the menu structure and then just strip out the SQL queries you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Would you put those two lines for bootstrapping in the Zend application.ini? We actually ended up going with our current configuration of calling the menu through and ajax request, except caching the menu in Zend. We set the cache for like 15 minutes. This reduced the number of ajax requests down from every page request to only one page request per user per 15 minute period. Dramatically less hits to the server. Thanks for your input. I like your suggestions.

Comment: Oh, and also, the menu system in Drupal is confounded. There are about 40 database hits for the menu; granted, they are only getting a row or few rows at a time, but rebuilding the menu from your own DB call is excessive and tedious. I wouldn't go this route. I spent an afternoon on it and felt more confused than when I started.

Comment: I'm not sure how Zend works, but the lines for bootstrapping should be before using the Drupal functions. And yes, it could lead to a lot of DB hits. That's why I was saying you should be doing this in a batch process, once a day and export it to a XML or something. Then for extra performance parse the XML and cache the menu structure in Zend. Sorry can't give any hints on how to integrate with Zend, I haven't worked with it.